# MySQL Query, problems with with duplicates on insert into

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, forum, xenforo

So I'm using the forum software Xenforo and I need help with a SQL query which will be executed periodically. The forum will have approximately 300-500 active users. So nothing too big.

### The goal:

All users `xf_users` need to be subscribed to `node_id 71` except users which are part of certain `user_group_id`.

Now users can unsubscribe from the forum or change the `notify_on` and `send_alert` & `send_email` fields. I do not want that. So if users 'unsubscribe' they need to be added again.

The only accepted change is that `notify_on` may also be "message".

**Summarized:**

- If the user is not on the table with `node_id 71`, then insert the users into `xf_forum_watch` with the `node_id 71`, `notify_on` is set to "thread" and `send_alert` & `send_email` are set to "1".
- If the line with the `user_id` and `node_id 71` exists, update `send_alert` and `send_email` to "1" if one of them is "0". If `notify_on` is blank: update to "thread".

### What I got so far:

My thought #1 was a trigger. Thing is, i have never written a trigger and don't know how to solve my issue with it.

Thought #2 was to write an "Event" in phpMyAdmin which runs a query periodically.

I got the code working for inserting all the right users into the list once but I'm having issues with keeping the list updated.

I have tried using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`... but I didn't get it to work like intended.

My quick&dirty solution would be to delete all lines of `node_id 71` and re-add all with the query below, but this wouldn't allow users to select `notify_on` "message". Also

Help? ♥

#### The table:

[Screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KIHE.png)

(!! the table will also include lines which are a different `node_id`. These must remain untouched !!)

#### The code:

```
insert into xf_forum_watch
    select user_id,
    "71" as node_id,
    "thread" as notify_on,
    "1" as send_alert,
    "1" as send_email
    from xf_user
where user_group_id NOT IN (1, 18, 40);
```

This will add the correct users to the list (see screenshot). However, it will throw an error if the user is already subscribed.

---

I hope that I didn't leave out any details. If there are still questions, please let me know.

I appreciate all kinds of help.

PS: I hope I didn't ruin the formatting. I am not used to posting here.

---

edit: Thanks to @GMB for their solution.

I have a follow-up question. I want to put the working query into a stored procedure but it gives me an error:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE forceSubscribeToNode(
    IN node_id_var INT
)
BEGIN
    insert into xf_forum_watch
    (user_id, node_id, notify_on, send_alert, send_email)
    select user_id,
    node_id_var as node_id,
    "thread" as notify_on,
    1 as send_alert,
    1 as send_email
    from xf_user
where user_group_id NOT IN (1, 18, 40)
on duplicate key update 
    send_alert = 1,
    send_email = 1,
    notify_on = case when notify_on is null or notify_on = '' then 'thread' else notify_on end
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 18`

(Line 18 being "send_email = 1,")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a `on duplicate key` to your query:

```
insert into xf_forum_watch
    (user_id, node_id, notify_on, send_alert, send_email)
    select user_id,
    71 as node_id,
    'thread' as on notify_on,
    1 as send_alert,
    1 as send_email
    from xf_user
where user_group_id NOT IN (1, 18, 40)
on duplicate key update 
    send_alert = 1,
    send_email = 1,
    notify_on = 'thread'
```

This assumes that you have the proper unique of primary key set up so that duplicates are properly identified.

If you want conditional logic in the `on duplicate key` clause, that’s also possible:

```
on duplicate key update 
    send_alert = case when send_alert = 0 then 1 else send_alert end,
    send_email = case when send_email = 0 then 1 else send_email end,
    notify_on = case when notify_on is null or notify_on = '' then  'thread' else notify_on end
```