# Error on creating a stored procedure in MySQL, Error#1064

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I'm having a hard time creating a stored procedure.
I have tried altering some things according to other entries on stack overflow but it did not help.

`select version();` returns `5.7.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` incase that helps.

### Here's the query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
PROCEDURE forceSubscribeToNode(IN node_id_var INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT
INTO
  xf_forum_watch(
    user_id,
    node_id,
    notify_on,
    send_alert,
    send_email
  )
SELECT
  user_id,
  node_id_var AS node_id,
  "thread" AS notify_on,
  1 AS send_alert,
  1 AS send_email
FROM
  xf_user
WHERE
  user_group_id NOT IN(
      1, 18, 40
  )
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
  send_alert = 1,
  send_email = 1,
  notify_on = CASE WHEN notify_on IS NULL OR notify_on = '' THEN 'thread' ELSE notify_on END
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Here's the error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 30`

(Line 18 is "send_email = 1,"

## For context, search engines and future reference:

This will be used for the forum software Xenforo 2.1 to force subscribe users to certain nodes like categories and sub-forums.

Comment: When there is a duplicate key, what do you want to happen?

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage Please see my other question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345517/

Comment: So your issue is resolved, it seems

Comment: @SrinikaPinnaduwage No.
This question is about turning the solution of the question that I linked into a stored procedure.

Comment: You say line 18 is `send_email = 1,` but the error is on line 30. I think you're just missing the semicolon.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It was the semicolon with a space before. phpMyAdmin counted the lines in the error message wrong. It ignored the Delimiter and so it was shifted by 1. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: It didn't seem to help, but you've posted it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I forgot to add a  `;` with a space before after the first `END`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
PROCEDURE forceSubscribeToNode(IN node_id_var INT)
BEGIN
  INSERT
INTO
  xf_forum_watch(
    user_id,
    node_id,
    notify_on,
    send_alert,
    send_email
  )
SELECT
  user_id,
  node_id_var AS node_id,
  "thread" AS notify_on,
  1 AS send_alert,
  1 AS send_email
FROM
  xf_user
WHERE
  user_group_id NOT IN(
      1, 18, 40
  )
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
  send_alert = 1,
  send_email = 1,
  notify_on = CASE WHEN notify_on IS NULL OR notify_on = '' THEN 'thread' ELSE notify_on END ;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```